# Wordpress Woocommerce Endpoint URL

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Have a wordpress/woo site and having an issue with the order-received message/page.

on checkout, after hitting "place order" the page acts as though nothing has happened yet the order comes through but it does not redirect to the standard checkout/order-received end point. 
I've tried custom redirect to different pages, double checked shop endpoints and they all seem valid and still nothing.

the shop url IS custom, so vs the standad /shop/ it's /product-collections/

other than than can't think of anything else. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: That certainly means that something is making trouble, a customization made by you, the theme or a plugin… Enable debug and look inside the debug.log file… You will find out what is making trouble.

Comment: thanks, yeah that's what am thinking but now need to disable plugins and see. Wish there was a way to disable plugins by user so site is still going